# flutter pub finished with exit code 64

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using

```
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.1
```

But it throws an error

pub finished with exit code 64

**Here is my pubspec.yaml code for flutter native splash**

```
name: abc

description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#32383D"

  image: assets/launch_image.png

  android: true

  ios: true


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

**Output:**

```
D:\StudioProjects\outloader>flutter clean
Deleting build...                                                  131ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              13ms
Deleting .packages...                                                3ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       3ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            3ms

    D:\StudioProjects\outloader>flutter pub get
    Running "flutter pub get" in abc...                           3.8s
    
    D:\StudioProjects\outloader>flutter pub run
    Must specify an executable to run.
    
    Usage: pub run <executable> [arguments...]
    -h, --help                              Print this usage information.
        --[no-]enable-asserts               Enable assert statements.
        --enable-experiment=<experiment>    Runs the executable in a VM with the
                                            given experiments enabled.
                                            (Will disable snapshotting, resulting in
                                            slower startup).
        --[no-]sound-null-safety            Override the default null safety
                                            execution mode.
    
    Run "pub help" to see global options.
    See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-run for detailed documentation.
    pub finished with exit code 64
```

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml file code

Comment: have a look, I have added whole pubspec.yaml file

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and remove below lines your pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_native_splash:
color: "#32383D"
```

Comment: Still it is not changing splash colour

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I managed to solve it.

Run the following commands sequentially after you saved the package in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter clean  
flutter pub get  
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```